# How do I calculated the second Reflection (2) of light in glass (which equations and tools)

Tags: visible-light, reflection, glass

How do I calculated the second Reflection (2) of light in glass (which equations and tools)
[image]

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the reflected(1) *and* refracted(1) rays at point "1"? If  you do know then at point "2" use the refracted(1) as the incident ray to calculate how it splits into newly reflected and refracted rays.

Comment: Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: hint: do you know how to calculate the reflected and refracted rays for an incident plane wave (ray) on a *single* flat surface? if not, this may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations